# what does the triangle in PDE notation mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

what does the triangle sign used in PDE equations represent?

example:
$$u_{tt}- \Delta u =0$$

I took the below example from the Evan's book PDE  p.4 (example 9). The equation is presented as the wave equation. I am not familiar with this notation and it is confusing to me. I know the wave equation in the form of $$u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 0$$ 
Could anybody clarify the notation? Are those two equations the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A capital delta $\Delta$ is sometimes used as notation for the Laplacian operator, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator. So yes the two equations are the same assuming that the Laplacian is one-dimensional in the first equation.

Comment: ok I understand that this represent a sum of partial derivatives in respect to all coordinates $$\Delta f= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2}$$ in the further example (p.9 example 2) the Poisson equation is presented as $$-\Delta u = f(u)$$ where does this minus come from then?

Comment: I know the Poisson equation in the form of $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = f(x,y)$

Comment: @Michal The extra minus sign is a convention taken by some authors, who choose to make the differential operator in their equation be the negative Laplacian instead of the Laplacian. They do this because it is a "positive" operator (it is analogous to a positive semidefinite matrix).

Comment: @Michal just as a side note the definition for the Laplacian you have given is not entirely correct, that definition is strictly only true in Cartesian coordinates. In different coordinate systems the Laplacian is different.

Answer (score -4):

The upside triangle ($\nabla$) is called the Laplacian. Usually one starts using it as you get PDE's that involve not just $u(x,t)$, but deals with function such as $u(x, y, t)$ or $u(x, y, z, t)$. Hence, with increments of the dimension the Laplacian is generalization of the second partial with respect to the coordinates.

\begin{equation*}
\nabla\phi=\phi_x+\phi_y
\end{equation*}
oR more general,
\begin{equation*}
\nabla\phi=\phi_{x_1}+\dots+\phi_{x_n}
\end{equation*}
where $x_i$ are nothing more than the coordinates that your applying the second partials to, namely the Laplacian operator.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please refer to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for proper LaTeX usage. You don't have to use \documentclass nor \begin{document} to initiate MathJax.

Comment: $\nabla$ is the gradient, not the Laplacian. Sometimes people write $\Delta$ for the Laplacian, other times $\nabla^2$, but never $\nabla$.

Comment: @user353052:  $\nabla$ that's nabla and it is something else, isn't it?

Comment: Also, the gradient itself is not the sum of the first partials, but the _vector_ of first partials...

Comment: Thank you the reference. Also, as a side note one can also take the Laplacian to equal the dot product of two gradient operators.